# How to force gcc to treat all input files as object files?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm trying to set up default compiler, linker, etc for a build script. I currently have this:

```
CC="gcc -std=gnu99 -c"
XX="g++ -std=gnu++11 -c"
LD="gcc"
```

This works fine, but gives me no warning if I accidentally pass a .c file to `$LD`, leaving a landmine for anyone who tryes to use a different LD. I'd like to use `LD="gcc -x [object]"`, but [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) doesn't list any name to use for `[object]`. (I've also tryed `LD="ld"` of course, but that produces such lovely errors as `ld: cannot find -lstdc++` and (*after* adding `-lc`) `ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400e60`.)

Comment: Solution: Don't pass a .c file

Comment: Yeah, makefiles aren't very good at error checking. You can add comments about potential land mines, and/or use `echo` to output the command lines. If you're really concerned about this, you can write a little script, or C program, that takes the linker command line, verifies the filenames, and then invokes `gcc`.